# How to fomat nested Json using Vanilla Js

Tags: javascript, json, frontend

I want to transform the Input JSON to Output Array of Objects, Use Input JSON array and use only vanilla Javascript, loop through JSON object. I tried foreach function but faced some issues. print output like given below

```js
let Input ={
       details:[
          {
             "id":"Country_name",
             "values":[
                "India",
                "England",
                "Germany"
             ]
          },
          {
             "id":"Country_capital",
             "values":[
                "Delhi",
                "London",
                "Berlin"
             ]
          }
       ],
       metadata:[
          {
             "id":"Country_name",
             "label":"Country"
          },
          {
             "id":"Country_capital",
             "label":"Capital"
          }
       ]
    }
    let Output =[
       {
          "Country":"India",
          "Capital":"Delhi"
       },
       {
          "Country":"England",
          "Capital":"London"
       },
       {
          "Country":"Germany",
          "Capital":"Berlin"
       }
    ]
    
Object.keys(input).forEach(function(value, key) {
  
   input[value].forEach(function(v, k) {
    console.log(v.id)
 })
})
```

Comment: You should add your code that you've attempted to your question.

Comment: Please provide the code that you have tried to improve so we can see the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this

```js
const input = {
  details: [{
      "id": "Country_name",
      "values": [
        "India",
        "England",
        "Germany"
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "Country_capital",
      "values": [
        "Delhi",
        "London",
        "Berlin"
      ]
    }
  ],
  metadata: [{
      "id": "Country_name",
      "label": "Country"
    },
    {
      "id": "Country_capital",
      "label": "Capital"
    }
  ]
};

function transform(input) {
  const ids = {};
  for (const detail of input.details) {
    ids[detail.id] = detail.values;
  }
  const meta = {};
  for (const m of input.metadata) {
    meta[m.id] = m.label;

  }
  const idsKeys = Object.keys(ids);

  const out = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < ids[idsKeys[0]].length; i++) {
    const obj = {};
    for (const key of idsKeys) {
      obj[meta[key]] = ids[key][i];
    }
    out.push(obj);
  }
  return out;
}

console.log(transform(input));
```

Comment: Insertion order is not maintained, Output not showing insertion order

Answer (score 0):

I changed the input and the variable in the top

This may work for you or not

```js
let input ={
       details:[
          {
             "id":"Country_name",
             "values":[
                "India",
                "England",
                "Germany"
             ]
          },
          {
             "id":"Country_capital",
             "values":[
                "Delhi",
                "London",
                "Berlin"
             ]
          }
       ],
       metadata:[
          {
             "id":"Country_name",
             "label":"Country"
          },
          {
             "id":"Country_capital",
             "label":"Capital"
          }
       ]
    }
    let Output =[
       {
          "Country":"India",
          "Capital":"Delhi"
       },
       {
          "Country":"England",
          "Capital":"London"
       },
       {
          "Country":"Germany",
          "Capital":"Berlin"
       }
    ]
    
Object.keys(input).forEach(function(value, key) {
  
   input[value].forEach(function(v, k) {
    console.log(v.id)
 })
})
```

If you have anymore questions or problems I would be happy to help

Answer (score 0):

- Countries are in `Input.details[0].values`
- Capitals are in `Input.details[1].values`

Just make an object containing country on one go through countries, then add capital to each one on second pass through capitals

```js
let Input = {
  details: [{
      "id": "Country_name",
      "values": [
        "India",
        "England",
        "Germany"
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "Country_capital",
      "values": [
        "Delhi",
        "London",
        "Berlin"
      ]
    }
  ],
  metadata: [{
      "id": "Country_name",
      "label": "Country"
    },
    {
      "id": "Country_capital",
      "label": "Capital"
    }
  ]
};
let Output = [{
    "Country": "India",
    "Capital": "Delhi"
  },
  {
    "Country": "England",
    "Capital": "London"
  },
  {
    "Country": "Germany",
    "Capital": "Berlin"
  }
];

const newOutput = [];

const countries = Input.details[0].values;
countries.forEach(country => {
  console.log(country);
  newOutput.push({"Country": country});
});

const capitals = Input.details[1].values;
capitals.forEach((capital, i) => {
  console.log(capital);
  newOutput[i]["Capital"] = capital;
});

console.log(newOutput);
```

Answer (score 0):

a shorthand method to do this is mapping the data arrays of `input` :

```js
let input ={
       details:[
          {
             "id":"Country_name",
             "values":[
                "India",
                "England",
                "Germany"
             ]
          },
          {
             "id":"Country_capital",
             "values":[
                "Delhi",
                "London",
                "Berlin"
             ]
          }
       ],
       metadata:[
          {
             "id":"Country_name",
             "label":"Country"
          },
          {
             "id":"Country_capital",
             "label":"Capital"
          }
       ]
    }
    let Output =[
       {
          "Country":"India",
          "Capital":"Delhi"
       },
       {
          "Country":"England",
          "Capital":"London"
       },
       {
          "Country":"Germany",
          "Capital":"Berlin"
       }
    ]


 let data = input.details
 let countries = data[0].values
 let capitals = data[1].values

 const output = countries.map((el, index) => ({"country": el, "capital": capitals[index]}))
 console.log(output)
```

However, in your code, you are referring to `Input` object as `input` , which are two different variables